# Adding values to an ArrayList<Number> each time a button is pressed

Tags: java, arraylist, actionlistener

this is my first post here, hope i'll get it right!!

what i did i created a NxN board with JButtons indicating the coordinates from [0, 0] to [9, 9].
each time a button is clicked the console shows the coordinates and what i tried to do is to save those coordinates in an ArrayList that will be displayed by pressing a second button in another window...nothing fancy, sorry, just wrapping my head around basic concepts...

the problem is that i can't get the values to be saved into the ArrayList and i can't then recall it once i press the second button...
attached the codes for my classes...each one is in a different file.

**Board.java**

```
public class Board{

public Board(){

    JFrame win = new JFrame ();
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(10, 10);
    win.setLayout(layout);
    for (int row1 = 0; row1 < 10 ; row1 = row1+1){
        for (int col1 = 0; col1 < 10; col1 = col1+1){
            JPanel jp = new JPanel();
            JButton jb = new JButton("[" + row1 + "," + col1 + "]");
            jb.addActionListener(new ButtonEventHandler(row1, col1));
            jp.add(jb);
            win.add(jp);
        }
        win.setVisible(true);
        win.pack();
}

    JFrame win2 = new JFrame("Stored values");
    win2.setVisible(true);
    JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
    win2.add(jp2);
    JButton jb2 = new JButton("Check Log");
    jb2.addActionListener(new Position(win2, jb2));
    jp2.add(jb2);
    win2.pack();
}}
```

**ButtonEventHandler.java**

```
public class ButtonEventHandler implements ActionListener {


private int _row1;
private int _col1;
private ArrayList<Number> _list;


public ButtonEventHandler(int row1, int col1){

    _row1 = row1;
    _col1 = col1;
    _list = new ArrayList<Number>();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Position: " + _row1 + ", " + _col1);
    _list.add(_row1);
    _list.add(_col1);
}

public ArrayList<Number> getList(){

    return _list;
}}
```

**Position.java**

```
public class Position implements ActionListener  {

private JFrame _win2;

private JButton _jb2;
private int _row1;
private int _col1;
private ArrayList<Number> _list;

private ButtonEventHandler beh = new ButtonEventHandler(_row1, _col1);


public Position(JFrame win2, JButton jb2){
    _win2 = win2;
    _jb2 = jb2;     
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    System.out.println(beh.getList());      
}
}
```

thanks so much for the help!!

Seb

Comment: tnx for formatting the post properly!

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you don't have one array list: you have *many* array lists. Each button handler has its own!

You should make one array list, and share it among all your handlers by passing it to their constructors.

```
public Position(JFrame win2, JButton jb2, AttayList<Number> list){
    _win2 = win2;
    _jb2 = jb2;
    _list = list;
}

public ButtonEventHandler(int row1, int col1, AttayList<Number> list) {
    _row1 = row1;
    _col1 = col1;
    _list = list;
}

public Board(){
    JFrame win = new JFrame ();
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(10, 10);
    win.setLayout(layout);
    ArrayList myList = new ArrayList<Number>();
    // In the code below, use myList as the last parameter to the constructors of ButtonEventHandler and Position
    ...
```

}

Comment: tnx for the reply...i see what u mean...but if i put the code like that when i click the button to check print the ArrayList out i get only "null" in the console....hmmmm....do i need to create i.e. a setList where i set the value of the list before the accessor method?

Comment: @Seb No, you already created an instance of the list in your `Board` constructor. You need to make sure that all 100 buttons get this list as the third parameter of their constructors, and that the `Position` gets the same instance as its last constructor parameter too.

Comment: both `ButtonEventHandler`and `Position` in the constructor, and in their instantiation in the `Board` class, have as third parameter `list`...in `Position` i have it like this `private ArrayList<Number> _list;
private ButtonEventHandler beh = new ButtonEventHandler(_row1, _col1, _list);`...would that be ok?

Comment: @Seb Could you update the question? The comments are not as readable as the question because of the formatting issues.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i had it to work :)

i changed the constructors as suggested, in the **Position** class i got the rid of

```
private ButtonEventHandler beh = new ButtonEventHandler(_row1, _col1, _list);
```

and changed the ActionPerformed to:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println(beh.getList()); //previous code, changed with the one below
    System.out.println(_list);
}
```

in this way i didn't need anymore the `getList` method in the **Board** class!

thanks for the help!!